# How to write a JavaScript function that will wait given milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, settimeout, wait

What I have attempted to do is write a function such as:

```
function delay(delay){
    var date = new Date();
    var startTime = date.getTime();


    var currDate=new Date();
    var current=currDate.getTime();

    while (current<=startTime+delay){
        currDate=new Date();
        current=currDate.getTime();
    }
}
```

This code seems to work perfectly when doing something such

```
console.log("1");
delay(500);
console.log("2");
```

When doing something like that, it will print out to the console 1, then wait half a second, then print out 2. The issue is that I don't want to console.log, I want to `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML+="a";`. When trying that surrounding the delay function, the page waits for all of the delay to finish before loading any of the a's.

My question is the following:

Is there a good way to either write such a function, or is there already a function, that can allow all previous code to run, cause a specified delay, and then run the code after it. I have tried using `setTimeout`, but the issue is that running something like this:

```
console.log("1");
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("2");
}, 2000);
console.log("3");
```

results in it printing 1, then printing 3, then waiting 2 seconds and printing 2, rather than doing 1, wait 2 secs, print 2, print 3

Clarification: The way I am trying to implement this is:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    document.getElementById("text")+="a";
    delay(500);    
}
```

What this code is supposed to do is print one letter at a time to the screen, with half a second in between each letter print

Comment: Why don't you add `console.log(3)` inside `setTimeout` when you don't want it to print before `2`?

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is the correct approach.

You would want

```
console.log("1");
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("2");
    console.log("3");
}, 2000);
```

which will log "1", wait 2s, then log "2" and "3" in that order.

The reason why your example doesn't work is because `setTimeout` is asynchronous.  That means that the function passed to `setTimeout` is scheduled for 2s from the time `setTimeout` is called but the program will continue executing any following lines.  Anything you want to wait until after the delay should be in the block inside `setTimeout`.

If you want further delays after your delay, you may call `setTimeout` from within the callback function.

For example:

```
console.log("1");
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("2");
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("3");
    }, 1000);
}, 2000);
```

Which will log "1", wait 2s, log "2", wait 1s, then log "3".

--

Loop with delay:

while () {
  console.log("1");
  (2000);
  console.log("2");
  console.log("3");
}

becomes

```
var loop = function() {
  console.log("1");
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("2");
    console.log("3");
    if (<condition>) {
      loop();
    }
  });
};
```

Note that for large numbers of iterations, you may exceed available stack.  In this case, you may resort to some workaround like `setTimeout(loop, 0);`

Comment: The issue with this is that I want to run the code in a loop and I want a particular action to take place, then a wait, and then the for loop should continue

Comment: I have updated my question to include what I want my code to do

Comment: In other words, how do I do synchronous things in an language and environment designed to be asynchronous (asynchronous = not wait for things)?  The problem is, if you tie up the CPU with a tight while loop, as you did in your question, the response of the UI will suffer.

Comment: If you want to continue looping, see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve something similar using callbacks:

```
function execute_after_delay( cb, msg, delay ){
   setTimeout(function(){
       console.log("2");
       cb(msg);
   }, delay);
}
console.log("1");
execute_after_delay(console.log, 3, 2000);
```